# Como inserir para todos os usuário em PLSQL quando não houver um dado?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

Boa tarde!

estou tentando inserir para **todos** os usuários quando não houver um tipo inserido para todos os usuários:

```
INSERT INTO USUARIO ( TIPO, PRIORITARIO)
SELECT  '130', 'N'
FROM dual
WHERE not exists (SELECT *
       FROM USUARIO
       WHERE tipo = '130' );
```

mas não estou conseguindo inserir , alguma idéia de como fazer ?

Comment: Claudio, utilize o botão [edit] para fazer alterações na pergunta e não nas respostas, ou adicione um comentário

Answer (score 1):

Faça assim:

```
merge into USUARIO a
     using (select '130' tipo, 'N' prioritario from dual) b
        on (a.tipo = b.tipo)
    when not matched then
     insert ( tipo, prioritario) values( b.tipo, b.prioritario )
```

Poderia ser assim tambem

```
merge
   into  usuario
   using (select count(*) as count from usuario where tipo = '130') a
     on   (a.count > 0)
 when not matched then
     insert (tipo, prioritario)
     values ('130', 'N');
```

Desse modo não tem aquela formatação valor, coluna, mas você precisa informar os valores das colunas duas vezes, o que deixa mais confuso.

Comment: Boa tarde, Sr. Reginaldo! 
Não tenho muita familiariadade com o PLSQL ,  primeira vez que vejo um  select assim  =  * select '130' tipo, 'N' prioritario * . --> Valor coluna , Interessante.
Vou testar amanhã.
Muito obrigado, pelo seu tempo,

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, você só vai criar o tipo 130 se ele não existir na base. Sendo assim, um *`IF`* resolve o problema:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE tipo = '130')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO USUARIO (TIPO, PRIORITARIO) VALUES ('130', 'N')
END
```